# vim fold text with spaces in front

Tags: vim, folding

I'm trying to customize vim folding style and stuck with indentation. I know it has been asked multiple times here and I use this command (which seem to work for others) to test the appearance of fold:

```
:set foldtext=' '.foldtext()
```

This however gives me 'unknown option' error. Apparently, it doesn't accept the string containing only space(s), because this

```
:set foldtext='mytext'.foldtext()
```

works fine and adds 'mytext' to the beginning of folds.

Why doesn't it work and what's the way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the space. Use this instead.

```
:set foldtext='\ '.foldtext()
```

The space is causing vim to think you want to set foldtext to `'` and then `'.foldtext()` is the next argument to set. However this isn't what you want and the reason the error message is

```
E518: Unknown option: '.foldtext()
```

Escaping the space tell vim that `foldtext='\ '.foldtext()` is one argument instead of two.

Comment: Aha, thanks! This works, strangely there are ~10 different versions I found online which didn't work for me but worked for others...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EightHeader](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4930) plugin if you prefer aligned foldtext. Example from the help:

If you don't like the default 'foldtext' you can customize it by setting to
`EightHeaderFolds()`.

For example the closed folds looks like this by default:

````
```+-- 45 lines: Fold level one
+--- 67 lines: Fold level two
````

If you would like to change it to this kind:

```
Fold level one................45 lines
  Fold level two..............67 lines
```

... then you can use this function:

```
let &foldtext = "EightHeaderFolds( '\\=s:fullwidth-2', 'left', [ repeat( '  ', v:foldlevel - 1 ), '.', '' ], '\\= s:foldlines . \" lines\"', '' )"
```